# Change select distinct SQL statement to work on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL statement that works on Postgresql and returns 2 columns ordering by other columns:

```
select distinct on (title) gender_id, title 
from persons
where account_id = 100
order by title, created_date
```

I need to change the SQL to work on SQL Server 2008 and Postgres, but in SQL Server I can't use the `on` clause How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by title order by created_date) as seqnum
      from persons p
      where account_id = 100
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

This version will work in both Postgres and SQL Server.

Note:  In Postgres, `distinct on` is usually faster than using `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
;with filterdData AS
(
select  top 100 percent
        gender_id, 
        title 
from persons
where account_id = 100
order by title, created_date
)
select Title, gender_id
from filterdData
gropup by Title, gender_id
```